# Extracting date from file name and making it a variable

Tags: r, regex, date, gsub, stringr

I have a list of files with names such as "MERRA2_300.tavg1_2d_flx_Nx.20050101.SUB.nc" and I need to combine all of these files using a loop, and create a variable in that new combined dataset which describes each observation with the date that corresponds to its file of origin.  All of the files have that exact same name, except for the date itself (ie. the next file is MERRA2_300.tavg1_2d_flx_Nx.20050102.SUB.nc)

I have written a loop as follows

```
wi <- list.files(path = ".")

final_data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 0)) 
colnames(final_data) <- c("PRECTOTCORR", "TLML", "lat", "lon", "time", "time_bnds", "date") 

for (i in wi) {
  nc<-open.nc(i)
  dat<-read.nc(nc) 

  date <- i

  dat$date <- date

  final_data <- rbind(final_data, dat)
}
```

The line `date <- i` is the crux of this question.  I know that using `gsub` or `stringr` or `regx` there is some kind of way to create a date variable for each observation, but I am confused by the operation and the syntax.

Ideally, an answer would create the variable such that it is understood as time series data by R, but that isnt absolutely necessary. Even if the variable is just created as a string, I can go from there to time series data on my own I think.

Comment: What can you rely on here?  Are the dates always in the same place in the file name?  Are they always in the same format (8 numbers: year, month, day)? Etc.

Comment: Yes, the file names are all the exact same except for the date. Should've clarified that, I'll add it to the original question

Comment: and yes, they are always in the format YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a bit of an answer to my own question, the gsub command does well to create a new variable from part of the file name.

```
wi1 <- "MERRA2_300.tavg1_2d_flx_Nx.20050101.SUB.nc"
nc1 <- open.nc(wi1)
dat1 <- read.nc(nc1)
dat1$date <- gsub("MERRA2_300.tavg1_2d_flx_Nx.|.SUB.nc", "", "MERRA2_300.tavg1_2d_flx_Nx.20050101.SUB.nc")
```

creates a date variable with the value 20050101

Currently trying to work this into the loop... perhaps:

```
for (i in wi) {
  nc<-open.nc(i)
  dat<-read.nc(nc) 

  dat$date <- gsub("MERRA2_300.tavg1_2d_flx_Nx.|.SUB.nc", "", i)

  final_data <- rbind(final_data, dat)
}
```